# Nautilus: add dynamic bookmark for sftp folder with changing IP?

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts, sftp, bookmarks

I would like to add a bookmark in nautilus to a sftp server whose ip address changes over time.

I am connecting through sftp to a (google cloud instance) server, inserting in the file explorer the address:

```
sftp://username@xx.xxx.xx.xx/home/
```

where xx.xxx.xx.xx is an IP address. I would like to add this as a bookmark in Nautilus, which I can easily do with `ctrl +d`. However, the ip address keeps changing from day to day. I can retrieve the IP address with a command like:

```
gcloud compute instances describe instancename --format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)"
```

Is there any way I can have a dynamic Nautilus bookmark, that would use the command above to create the correct address? Or can I run a command myself to update a static nautilus bookmark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a fake domain pointing to the ip.

Edit `/etc/hosts` and add

```
xx.xxx.xx.xx    my_foo_domain
```

To access then you just insert `sftp://your_user@my_foo_domain`

This way you don't have to create a shortcut everytime, but you have to *edit* `/etc/hosts` everytime. You can create a command to refresh the ip, like (backup your `/etc/hosts`):

```
sed -i -E 's/^[.0-9]*[[:blank:]](my_foo_domain)/<your new ip> \1/' /etc/hosts
```

You can create a function placed in your `.bahsrc`:

```
_renew_ip() {
  ip=$(gcloud compute instances describe instancename --format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)")
  sed -i -E "s/^[.0-9]*[[:blank:]]*(my_foo_domain)/$ip \1/" /etc/hosts
}

alias renew_ip='bash -c "$(declare -f _renew_ip); _renew_ip"' 
alias sudo='sudo '
```

And then you can just call the function:

```
sudo renew_ip
```

Comment: Nice!! How can I plug-in the IP address given by `gcloud compute ...` into the `<your new ip>` in the sed call? And also, for the sake of completeness, maybe could mention in post: 1) one would use my_foo_domain in the sftp call, right? 2) editing /etc/hosts requires sudo ? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Editing `/etc/hosts` requires sudo, yes

Comment: Does the command you mention give a *clean* ip, no other text?

Comment: Wait, I have to solve the permissions issue for the function to work properly.

Comment: oh wow, niiice! I had to edit the quotation marks as there are outer and inner ones? But when I run the code, it does not execute the ip line, just pates it? I mean I get the line `gcloud compute instances...` copied in`/etc/hosts`. I believe the command I use returns just the clean IP, at least it pritns it in the terminal, see description: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry it shouldn't have been just double quotes! Try this in a terminal: `ip=$(gcloud compute instances describe instancename --format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)"); echo $ip` to see if it gives the desired output.

Comment: It does indeed return the value as expected! `echo $ip
12.123.xx.xx`

Comment: ok, it works now, the issue was with the `ip="gcloud ...` line, which works when using instead the $ `ip=$(gcloud` as in your current answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello! Yes I was going to write you about it, glad it works for you!

Comment: Hi  schrodigerscatcuriosity!, one more question: is there  away to run the command where sudo only applies to the `sed` line? I think having sudo apply tp `gcloud compute` create problems, as I would need to log into gcloud as sudo too, which so far is not necessary. Thanks!